# How to get dates for Billing cycle of an Azure Subscription

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I need the Azure subscription Billing dates to calculate the outstanding billing amount in the current Billing Cycle.
To calulate the usage amount I am using Azure Billing API's (Rate Card API and Usage API). From this i can only get usage for a time stamp.

```
string requestRateCardAPIurl = String.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2015-09-01+00%3a00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2015-09-07+00%3a00%3a00Z", subscriptionId);

string requestUsageAPIurl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}",
                   "https://management.azure.com",
                   "subscriptions",
                   subscriptionId,
                   "providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'ms-azr-0059p' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'");
```

Is there any API or some function to get the Billing Cycle Details?